# AppleTV 4 - how to disable Bluetooth needed to pair AirPlay device

Tags: bluetooth, airplay

In our large auditorium, an A/V rack which contains an AppleTV 4 for use as an AirPlay device to our humongous projector, sits in the back of the room in a closet. The ATV4, with the latest tvOS, uses a combination of Bluetooth and Wifi to establish a Conference Room Display connection from an Airplay-enabed device (laptop, iPad, etc.)

Naturally, Bluetooth's limited range makes it impossible to connect with AirPlay from the presenter's lectern on-stage, being almost 150' distant from the ATV4. One can connect when in range of the ATV4, and then move the AirPlay-enabled device to the lectern, but that is extremely non-optimal.

I've searched for quite a while on how to disable this function, but it doesn't seem to be possible. I've also searched for Bluetooth extender devices, but they seem be designed to extend audio connections to BT headphones & whatnot.

Has anybody figured out how to disable the peer-to-peer Bluetooth AirPlay configuration and use just Wi-fi?

Comment: Is the Apple TV connected to the same Wi-Fi as the lecturer’s device(s)

Comment: Experimenting with an ATV4 running tvOS 11.2.1, one does not need to have the ATV connected to a wireless network at all. Connecting with Bluetooth creates an ad-hoc wifi network between the source device and the ATV itself. There seems to be no way around this.

Comment: But you’re able to airplay through the existing network, which means you’re able to do it from everywhere in the range of the WiFi router/wired connection without the Bluetooth stuff...

Comment: When I turn Bluetooth off on the source device, there is no wifi connection. The ATV is also not connected to our enterprise wifi, either. I'm working with out networking dude to look at the net traffic, but he's busy for the next few days updating our Aruba controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difficulty was manifold, and combined a misconfigured wifi network, ATV4s not at the latest version of tvOS, and a management profile with an out-of-date certificate. Once these obstacles were overcome, the need to connect with Bluetooth was made moot.